# htaccess - Appending http_referer query string parameters to the requested uri using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am pretty new to htaccess and how to use them so you'l have to bear with me a little.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

I am on a page with the following URL: https://www.example.com/you?source=hissite

While on this page I click on a link to another page of my site with an href of https://www.example.com/him.

Is it possible to use htaccess to append the parameters of the referal url into the requested url, this way I end up on https://www.example.com/him?source=hissite ?

This question gave me some good clues but I couldn't figure out how to append only the parameters. [Redirect using htaccess based on referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106299/redirect-using-htaccess-based-on-referrer)

Comment: Hi @anubhava this is just an example to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish. I don't actually own this domain or have any control over it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the htaccess rules wouldn't change if it were on this domain or another. If they did, it would be the URL part of a regex that would need to be replaced. The real-life context of my question is on a corporate domain that is not exposed to the public. If you look at the question linked at the end of my question, they also use example URLs, because in the end this doesen't have an impact on the answer.